# How to create Input value in javascript

Tags: javascript

My objective is to create a input and append a value with javascript

This is my code:

```
count = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
text = document.createElement('input');
text.className='text1';
node = document.getElementsByClassName('text1').value ='Enter';
document.body.append(text);
```

Comment: which value is the value to be appended? `node` wil be 'Enter' as far as I can see it

Comment: If any of the provided solution worked please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `getElementsByClassName` since you already have the new input in your `text` variable.

```js
var count = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
var text = document.createElement('input');
text.className='text1';
text.value ='Enter';
document.body.append(text);
```

Comment: He probably knows this already, since he adds `text` to the body already

Comment: @Icepickle He probably hardly knows, because why else would he use `getElementsByClassName` when it is not needed, does not work, and leads to a question on SO.

Comment: @PeterB If that is the question, then it should be closed at a duplicate, but I really don't know what the op means with appending the value to something, so I rather don't think the question should be answered at all

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` [does not return a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method), and even if it did: The element you are trying to modify hasn't been added to the document you are searching!

You already have the element in the `text` variable. Use that:

```
text.value = "Enter";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `getElementsByClassName` because, the lement is not appended to the document yet.

```js
    text = document.createElement('input');
    text.className='text1';
    text.value ='Enter';
    document.body.append(text);
```

Alternatively You can use `getElementsByClassName` but only after you have appended the element to the document. But as `getElementsByClassName` selects multiple elements you have to define an index:

```js
    text = document.createElement('input');
    text.className='text1';
    document.body.append(text);
    document.getElementsByClassName('text1')[0].value = 'Enter';
```

Instead of `class` you can use an `id`:

```js
    text = document.createElement('input');
    text.id='text1';
    document.body.append(text);
    document.getElementById('text1').value = 'Enter';
```

Comment: @cord If this solution was helpful please be sure to accept it.